# conditional join between several tables of moodle's database

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements, moodle

I need to create a join query between several tables based on the output of some previous table. I am trying to use case when statement as follows but its showing error! any kind of help is appreciated

```
SELECT completion.userid, completion. coursemoduleid, completion. timemodified, 
module.course, user. idnumber as student_id, m.name as module_name, activity.name as activity_name
FROM `mdl_course_modules_completion` as completion

join mdl_course_modules as module 
on completion. coursemoduleid = module.id

join mdl_user as user on user.id = completion.userid

join mdl_modules as m on completion. coursemoduleid = m.id

join 
CASE WHEN module_name = 'assign'THEN 'mdl_assign'
     WHEN module_name = 'assignment'  THEN 'mdl_assignment'
     ELSE "quiz"
END AS activity

on activity.id = m.id LIMIT 0, 30
```

[image]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post. PS Clearly there is non-minimal code/data here.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "conditional join". Instead you can use two LEFT JOINs and COALESCE():

```
SELECT completion.userid,
  ...
  COALESCE(activity1.name, activity2.name) as activity_name -- SELECT first non NULL value
FROM `mdl_course_modules_completion` as completion
...
LEFT JOIN mdl_assign activity1
  ON  activity1.id = m.id    -- JOIN condition
  AND module_name = 'assign' -- CASE condition
LEFT JOIN mdl_assignment activity2
  ON  activity2.id = m.id        -- JOIN condition
  AND module_name = 'assignment' -- CASE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you -

```
SELECT completion.userid, completion. coursemoduleid, completion. timemodified, 
module.course, user. idnumber as student_id, m.name as module_name,(CASE WHEN (a.name != '') THEN a.name ELSE (CASE WHEN (ass.name != '') THEN ass.name ELSE q.name END) END) as activity_name
FROM `mdl_course_modules_completion` as completion
join mdl_course_modules as module 
on completion. coursemoduleid = module.id
join mdl_user as user on user.id = completion.userid
join mdl_modules as m on completion. coursemoduleid = m.id
left join mdl_assign as a on a.id = m.id
left join mdl_assignment as ass on ass.id = m.id
left join mdl_quiz as q on q.id = m.id
where m.name in ('assign','assignment','quiz')
LIMIT 0, 30
```